# Transiting Singapore via VFTF

Tags: indian-citizens, singapore, vftf

I am an Indian citizen and hold a valid Japan visa. I will be transiting via Singapore while returning from Bali/Philippines.

I came across an article which stated that Indian citizens can avail 96 hours VFTF *([Visa Free Transit Facility](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-depart/entry_requirements/visa-free-transit-facility))* facility if they hold a valid Japan visa however granting VFTF will be at sole discretion of immigration officer.

So I am wondering if I should apply for a normal visa because VFTF is at discretion of immigration officer.
Any inputs on VFTF will be helpful like should I plan my trip relying on VFTF?

Post travel Update:

I was able to travel to Singapore based on Japan visa via VFTF. However immigration officer was not aware of VFTF based on Japan visa and I had to share all details from my side after which he consulted other officer and then granted visitor pass.
So my suggestion would be to carry all details with you.

Comment: Thanks for posting the update!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not need a Transit visa if you have a multiple (2 or more)-entry Japanese visa (It is clearly written on the visa)

If your visa is single-entry (Single-Journey here), you only qualify if either :

You have not spent that entry (i.e you have never entered Japan on that particular visa)

or

> - A visa is considered valid so long as it is good for entry into one of the eight countries listed above. Travellers with Single Journey Visas (SJV) may still be granted VFTF on the return leg of their journey (i.e. after the SJV is used and no longer valid), but you must:

> - Travel directly from the country that issued the SJV, en route through Singapore, back to your home country
> - Not have returned to your home country since you last used the SJV.

From [ICA](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-depart/entry_requirements/visa-free-transit-facility)

Visas for Japan, outside of business travel are likely to be only single entry :

> Visas are only valid for entering Japan on one occasion. The period of validity of the single-entry visa is three months.

> Multiple-entry visas can be issued to business travelers, etc. The period of validity of these visas is from one to five years, and these visas can be used any number of times during their period of validity.

From [MOFA](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/procedure/validity.html)

> because VFTF is at discretion of immigration officer.

Entering another country than one of citizenship is a privilege and not a right, every time you enter a foreign country, the IO can do *whatever they want* with your entry.

> So I am wondering if I should apply for a normal visa

Except if you hold a multiple-entry visa, this is likely your only choice

Comment: Thanks. I hold a multi entry visa for Japan.